# Will killing chkdsk on a PSP damage the memory card?

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk, memory-card

I have a PSP connected to the PC via data cable. It has a Memory Stick Pro Duo Adapter that contains a 32gb Micro SD card. Awhile ago, the cable got disconnected unexpectedly and when I plug the PSP back in to the PC with USB Mode, it now shows the Scan and Fix prompt. I tried clicking on it but the window just closes and it doesn't do a thing. I tried replugging the PSP and it continously shows the Scan and Fix prompt. Clicking on fix just closes the window and nothing happens.

This prompted me to use `chkdsk /x /r drive:`. It found an error as follows:
[image]
However, it's taking too long to finish. Pressing Ctrl+C doesn't stop the process either. So I was hoping of using taskkill to just kill the chkdsk process. I want to know if this can damage the memory card itself in some way or will it just corrupt the data inside and a format will fix everything?

Comment: If one of the first steps of chkdsk is taking a very long time this can indicate a general hardware problem with the memory card.

Answer (score 0):

It will either not make the situation worse (you’ll need another chkdsk on it to fix the filesystem; you can do that on your desktop computer as well though), or you’ll have a partially repaired filesystem (which may be worse but usually isn’t), but this all affects the data on the card only.

You will always be able to create a new filesystem (“reformat”) the card, even if you cancel CHKDSK, unless the medium itself is broken (which should not happen from a mere power outage; flash storage usually only breaks if a block is written-to too oftenly).